# How can I construct a scipy linkage matrix given a binary tree?

Tags: python, scipy, binary-tree, linkage, dendrogram

I know there's the [to_tree()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.to_tree.html) method to convert a linkage matrix to a tree, but how can I do the opposite? Specifically, given a simple nested list representing a binary tree, how do I obtain the corresponding linkage matrix? Let's ignore the distance and number of observations (they are irrelevant for the construction of the linkage matrix).

Here's what I tried:

```py
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram
tree = [[[[0, [1, [2, 3]]], 4],
  [[[5, [6, 7]], [8, 9]], [10, [[11, [12, 13]], [14, 15]]]]],
 [[[16, [[17, [18, 19]], [[20, 21], [22, [23, 24]]]]],
   [[[25, 26], [[27, 28], [29, 30]]],
    [[[[[31, 32], 33], [34, 35]], [[36, 37], [[38, 39], [40, 41]]]],
     [42, [43, 44]]]]],
  [[[45, 46], [47, [[48, 49], [50, [[51, 52], 53]]]]],
   [[[[[54, 55], 56], [57, 58]], 59], [60, [[61, 62], [63, 64]]]]]]]

n_clusters = 65
linkage = []
def tree_to_linkage(tree):
    a, b = tree
    if isinstance(a, list):
        a = tree_to_linkage(a)
    if isinstance(b, list):
        b = tree_to_linkage(b)
    linkage.append((a, b, 1, 0))
    return(n_clusters + len(linkage))
tree_to_linkage(tree)
dendrogram(np.array(linkage, dtype="float64"))
```

But I get **ValueError: Linkage 'Z' uses non-singleton cluster before it is formed.**

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. The solution is to repeatedly prune those nodes that merge two leaves, so that the numbering of internal nodes becomes what is expected for the linkage matrix. Here's a function that takes a ClusterNode representing the tree (i.e. the inverse of `to_tree()`):

```py
    from copy import deepcopy
    from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import ClusterNode

    def to_linkage(tree: ClusterNode, n_clusters):
        tree = deepcopy(tree)
        linkage = []
        # Remove all nodes that merge two leaves, and place them on the linkage list
        def prune(tr):
            if tr.left.is_leaf() and tr.right.is_leaf():
                linkage.append((tr.left.id, tr.right.id, tr.dist, tr.count))
                tr.id = n_clusters + len(linkage) - 1
                tr.left = None
                tr.right = None
            if tr.left is not None and not tr.left.is_leaf():
                prune(tr.left)
            if tr.right is not None and not tr.right.is_leaf():
                prune(tr.right)

        while not tree.is_leaf():
            prune(tree)

        return np.array(linkage, dtype="float64")
```